# Setting defaults in EntityFramework 5 Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm using a Entity Framework Database First workflow.

I created my model, and I have successfully moved my .tt file for the entity/class generation into a separate project as recommended by Julie Lerman's Pluralsite course (I'm new to EF)

I am creating partial classes for each entity class and I want to set some defaults.  The obvious answer (which is the answer to similar questions) is to do this in a constructor. The problem is my generated entities already have a constructor.  EG:

-- Generated class --

```
 public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.EmailLogs = new HashSet<EmailLog>();
        this.Listings = new HashSet<Listing>();
        this.Visitors = new HashSet<Visitor>();
    }
```

-- Recommended Approach --

```
  public User()
   {
       this.CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now;
       this.IsAdminUser = false;
       this.Token = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

This fails because I cannot have 2 partial constructors.

I want these properties set in the DotNet Layer (instead of DB defaults) because I want them populated when I work with a new object before saving.

I want to be able to round-trip edits to my model, ie, if I add another property to the object, I want to be able to re-code-gen my entity classes.  Therefore, editing the entity classes manually isn't a really a great answer.

Surely there is an obvious solution that I'm missing.